# After Effects: How do I hide the wire mesh for puppet tool?

Tags: after-effects, motion-graphics

I have a composition that has a puppet pin tool added for a simple head movement. The head animation works fine but when I move the frame, there seems to be a wire mesh left behind. I have created a Null Object as a controller and attached all of the layers to transition them out of the frame. Attached is a screenshot of the wire mesh.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Collapse Transformations (the sun) icon [image: sun] ticked on your puppet layer?  That seems to break the puppet pin tool for me.

Comment: Yes, I have it ticked on since these are vector files

Comment: See this reply: https://community.adobe.com/t5/after-effects-discussions/continuous-rasterization-and-the-puppet-pin-tool-possible-questions-and-problems/m-p/10205413